# Rails counter cache updating by 2 on record update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a User model and a PullRequest model tracking Github pull requests. My user model has:

`has_many :pull_requests_as_creator, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'creator_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pull_requests_as_merger, class_name:'PullRequest', foreign_key: 'merger_id', dependent: :destroy`

and my PullRequest model has:

```
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', counter_cache: :pull_requests_created_count
  belongs_to :merger, class_name: 'User', counter_cache: :pull_requests_merged_count
```

If I first add a pull request with no merger_id then it's fine, creator count gets updated by 1 - but if the pull request gets merged, the record gets updated with a merger_id and it's count jumps up by 2 (the creator count stays as it was) - if I add a pull request that initially has a merger and a creator then both get incremented by 1 and everything is fine.

What could be causing this issue? I've tried adding a before_save: callback to first decrement the counter by 1 (I'd rather not have to do this!) but that didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why this occurs - I thought maybe it was because the counter functionality might be bound to after_save and after_destroy callbacks but that doesn't explain what makes it increment twice.

I have used an after_apdate callback that does

```
  after_update :update_counter

  def update_counter
    User.reset_counters(self.merger.id, :pull_requests_as_merger)
  end
```

Hope this helps anyone else having a similar issue.